# Por que criar um slice com tamanho variável é mais lento?

Tags: golang

Usando o `make([]byte, tamanho)` ele tem um comportamento diferente quando o `tamanho` é uma variável ou uma constante.

Considere os dois códigos:

```
package Testes

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkConstante(b *testing.B) {
    const tamanho = 1024
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = make([]byte, tamanho)
    }
}
func BenchmarkVariavel(b *testing.B) {
    var tamanho = 1024
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = make([]byte, tamanho)
    }
}
```

> A única diferença entre os dois é o `const` e `var`.

Eles retornam:

```
50000000            35.5 ns/op
10000000           181 ns/op
```

Ambos possuem o mesmo `tamanho`, de 1024. A única diferença é que o primeiro é constante (também tem o mesmo efeito se usar `make([]byte, 1024)` diretamente), mas o segundo caso é mais lento que o primeiro.

Usar a primeira forma consegue ser cinco vezes mais rápido do que se utilizar uma variável. Agora, porque isso ocorre? Porque usar um valor variável consegue ter uma diferença *tão grande*?

*Acredito que ambos sejam suficientemente rápidos, mas o que é estranho é haver um diferença tão grande para algo tão simples.*

---

Meu chute é que o compilador consegue reduzir alguma coisa quando se utiliza um valor constante. Enquanto isso, usar uma variável adicionaria algumas outras verificações, por exemplo verifica se o valor é menor do que zero, isso não precisa ao usar um valor constante, já que isso é feito no momento em que compila.

Acredito que possa ser algo deste tipo, mas o que seria exatamente?

Comment: O que são esses números que precedem os tempos?

Comment: Os números indicam a quantidade de iterações e o tempo que demorou para cada uma, [ao menos é a informação que consta no manual](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).

Comment: Acredito que a suposição esteja correta :) Constância faz milagres...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em golang quando você cria uma constante ela é uma literal, um valor escalar que pode ou não ser nomeado. Em outras palavras, seu valor ou expressão fica diretamente definido em tempo de compilação como se tivéssemos escrito diretamente no código. Vejamos dois casos:

No primeiro, escrevemos uma constante e depois duas variáveis e logo em seguida sua concatenação. No segundo caso, mudamos apenas v1 para ser uma constante. O resultado em ambos os casos é  `Hello, Ari`, no entanto o comportamento na compilação é diferente.

```
//primeiro caso
func main() {
    const v0 = "Hello, "
    var v1 = "Ari"
    var v2 = v0 + v1
    println(v2)
}

//segundo caso
func main() {
    const v0 = "Hello, "
    const v1 = "Ari"
    var v2 = v0 + v1
    println(v2)
}
```

No primeiro caso existe uma alocação de v1 para o heap e isto faz com que a operação de concatenação tenha que ir buscar o valor e depois concatenar. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No segundo caso é a mesma coisa de escrevermos literalmente ```v2 = "Hello, Ari", veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, o custo de ir buscar o valor e depois operar sobre ele é mais custoso do que manter o valor diretamente no código compilado. Isto é óbvio!
Tecnicamente, pode-se afirmar que *const* trabalham em tempo de compilação e *var* trabalham em tempo de runtime.

Dito isto, podemos facilmente entender que se consumirmos o heap com essa constante, o custo de mantê-lo lá não compensa mais, quando comparado a uma variável. Ou seja, se você, literalmente aumentar gradativamente o tamanho do seu slice verá que chegará um momento onde tanto constantes como variáveis possuem o mesmo custo. Assim, se você utilizar, por exemplo, `[const|var] tamanho = 64 * 1024` o resultado será como se segue (o primeiro é 16*1024 e o segundo é 64*1024):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*P.S.: a diferença no segundo caso é insignificante, dado diversas execuções.*